# ruby on rails - Search form with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models, Post and Location, where location has_many posts and post belongs_to location. I want to make a search function with 3 conditions. With the following code it did not return any thing in my testing.

View
search.html:

```
<%= form_tag search_posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:title] %>
        <%= text_field_tag :company, params[:company] %>
        <%= select_tag :location_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Location.all, :id, :name, params[:location_id]), include_blank: true %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller
post_controller.rb:

```
  def search
    title = params[:title]
    company = params[:company]
    location_id = params[:location_id]
    @posts = Post.search(title, company, location_id)
  end
```

Model Post.rb

```
def self.search(title, company, location_id)
    return scoped unless title.present? || company.present? || location_id.present?
where(['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", "%#{location_id}%"])
end
```

Comment: can u see in the terminal(server log), what query it makes for searching?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "title"=>"key", "company"=>"tra", "location_id"=>"1"
}
  [1m[35mPost Load (3.0ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (title LIK
E '%key%' AND company LIKE '%tra%' AND location_id = '%1%')

Comment: Hi Gopal, still the same...

Comment: Have you taken location_id as string on posts table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of '%' for location_id if location_id is not a string.Hope this helps.

Model Post.rb

```
def self.search(title, company, location_id)
  return scoped unless title.present? || company.present? || location_id.present?
  where(['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#    
  {company}%", location_id])
end
```

Comment: One more question: how to add a priority option into the select_tag?

Comment: Do you mean the order of options in select tag?

Comment: Something like that. Use Location.order()?

Comment: How to add pagination to the search result? And also with a limit on the search result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need % around our location_id and you shouldn't convert it to string

Few debugging tips for future reference:

a) Check whether this actually should return anything - does such a record exists in current db?

b) Try runnig the query through console. You can use`.to_sql` on relation object to see what SQL is executed

c) If no results, try break your where conditions and check which bit works and which doesn't (I'm almost sure the problem is related with data types for location_id)